# Ordered list using repeater in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code below keeps giving me an error:

Repeater code in .ASPX file

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDescription" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate><ol class="DescriptionRepeater"></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><%= this %></a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate><ol/></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code to populate the repeater in .ASPX.CS file

im using visual studio 2017 the code is causing the ordered list to be filled with the path to the .aspx file

```
List<string> lstDescription = new List<string>();
        lstDescription.Add("this is the first description");
        lstDescription.Add("this is the second description");
        rptDescription.DataSource = lstDescription;
        rptDescription.DataBind();
```

Comment: You need to use `<%# Container.DataItem %>` instead of `<%= this %>`. `this` would refer to the current context which usually is current page.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a practical scenario. Anyhow, you just use `Container.DataItem`, since `DataItem` itself is a string. Please make sure you use binding syntax `<%#  %>` instead of `<%= %>`.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDescription" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ol class="DescriptionRepeater">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><%# Container.DataItem %></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <ol />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater
```